# vim "modeline" equivalent for eclipse?

Tags: vim, eclipse, file-format

In our project different developers use different editing tools. Some use vim, some use eclipse. The nature of the project requires some files with DOS line endings, some with Unix line endings. It sometimes happens that the line ending type gets mixed up in files. Vim users do not have this problem because each file contains a commented "modeline" that looks like

```
/* vi: set fileformat=dos: */
```

or

```
# vi: set fileformat=unix
```

near the EOF which tells vim to do the right thing.

Can eclipse be made to do the same on a per-file basis? I.e. can I tell eclipse within a file "This is a DOS file; save it with DOS line endings and convert if needed."?

Note: it is not an option to

- force vim on developers
- add file properties in eclipse that need to be maintained
- run external tools

Answer (score 0):

```
File ---> Convert Line Delimiters To ---> Unix || Windows || Mac OS 9
```

Comment: But that's a manual operation. The question is how to do this automatically, as indicated in the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is **[EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/)**. It allows specifying text file specific config options such as line endings or indentation in a standardized way. There are [plugins](http://editorconfig.org/#download) for both [Vim](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim#readme) and [Eclipse](https://github.com/ncjones/editorconfig-eclipse#readme).